# Error populate textbox JS - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code.
The objective of this js is through the dropwdown load the textbox UserMR
But it never finds the UserMR.
I call UserMr model inside Star instantiating a new object.

relationships:
Star contains idModel
Model does not contain IDStar

What is going on?

**Model**

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(StarValidation), "DateValidate")]
    public partial class Star
    {
        public virtual string UserMR { get { return this.User.UserMR; } set { this.UserMR = value;} }

        public Model User = new Model();
```

**View inside "STAR"**

```
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.IdModel, "StarModel", new { onchange = "updateUserMR($(this))" })
@Html.DisplayFor(i => i.UserMR)

<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateUserMR(model) {
            var user = model.brother("@Html.NameFor(x => x.UserMR)"); 
            var idModel = model.val();
            user.empty();
            if (idModel != null && idModel != "")
                user.loadOptions("@Url.Action("ListJsonUserMR", "Model")?idModel=" + idModel, true, true);
            }
    </script>
```

**Controller**

```
  public JsonResult ListJsonUserMR(int idModel)
    {
        var model = this.service.GetUserMr(idModel).Select(x => new
        {
            Value = x.Id,
            Description = x.UserMR
        });
        return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Service**

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetUser(int idModel)
        {
            return base.context.Models
                .Where(x => x.Id == idModel);
        }
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: What is `model.brother` coming from?

Comment: Brother is a defined function. var brother = $("input[name=" + name + "]", parent);

Comment: Have you checked the value of your `user` variable? Correct syntax is `$("input[name=" + name + "]").parent();`

Comment: None of your code makes sense. `var user = model.brother("@Html.NameFor(x => x.UserMR)");` will be `undefined` and what is `user.loadOptions(..)`?